# Using a Pre-Made Dendrogram to Order Samples in Heatmap3 in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm trying to use `heatmap3` to visualize my bacterial community data. I have already clustered my samples, and have a dendrogram from `hclust` that I want to use to order my samples in the heatmap, while showing the dendrogram as well. However, the data file that I am putting into heatmap3 has been collapsed to the genera level, so the structure that I had before isn't immediately apparent to heatmap3, and I therefore don't want heatmap3 to try to do its own clustering.

I've tried using my hclust object as a dendrogram and passing it to Colv, but the order of the samples in my heatmap, for whatever reason, becomes literally random while the dendrogram looks correct. When I extract the order of samples in my dendrogram and re-order my input matrix according to this order (without a dendrogram), I get visible clustering. Essentially what I want is to give heatmap my dendrogram that I made from an hclust function, and have it order the samples in *that* order WITH the dendrogram above, and then plot the relative abundances in the heatmap. What am I missing?

Unfortunately I don't have data that I'm able to provide, or an illustrative example. If this question is impossible to answer without data and R code, I will do my best to put something together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pheatmap` package there parameters `cluster_rows` and `cluster_cols` accept hclust objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still having the same issue that I note in paragraph 2, where adding `cluster_cols` as my hclust object seems to be almost randomly shuffling the samples around, but ordering my samples by the cluster that they belong in by cutting the tree and extracting those names seems to still work (but lacks the tree..)... Maybe it's a complete misunderstanding of how I should be using my hclust object? Maybe I need to do a bunch of stuff to it or my matrix first?

Comment: is it possible you reordered your matrix after hclust and before heatmap?

Comment: Yep, that would do it... The distance matrix that I was using to generate the hclust object was not in the same order as the samples in the matrix that went into the data frame. I thought that the heatmap function would be able to align the samples between the hclust and the matrix, but apparently not. All is well now! :)